# Return RESTful/json response instead of login form in Spring boot OAUTH2

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm struggling to return a json response when the user is nog logged in, instead of returning a html login form.

The application is only using @RestController's and I do not want any web support.

```
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable();
```

When I do a get request using the browser or postman, I receive back the default spring HTML login form.

```
security.basic.enabled=true
```

I'm using OATH2, and when I request a token it works great and I get a response like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "227803d1-fe94-4e31-b496-3a03bafb9479",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "322f4ee9-4c48-4e06-a129-f4b6af93d664",
  "expires_in": 43199,
  "scope": "read write"
}
```

Somehow, it works correct in this example:

https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth

And when I'm not authorized, I want back something like this:

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
}
```

But I'm getting a login form, and I want the response above. What am I doing wrong? I litterally can't uderstand why it works in the GitHub example, and not in my case. Is there a way to completely disable the login form, and force the json response?

Comment: so why you add `.formLogin()` to your config ?

Comment: even without is does

Answer (score 4):

Will need a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and override the `commence()` method.

Indeed, the entry point has to be registered in the Spring Security config

```
http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
```

Sample code:

```
public class UserAuthenticationEntryPoint implements
        AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ex)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getOutputStream().print("{\"error\":\"Unauthorized.. Please authenticate..\"}");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`AuthenticationEntryPoint` is used for exception handling in spring security.

If you have added the oauth2 to your pom, you can use `OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint` for you entry point, the Entry point is for spring security exception handling, if you are using the basic for your authentication, you can config like this

```
http
  .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(getCustomerEntryPoint());

@Bean
protected AuthenticationEntryPoint getCustomerEntryPoint() {
    return new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
}
```

as you can see the exception handling in `OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint`

```
// Try to extract a SpringSecurityException from the stacktrace
    Throwable[] causeChain = throwableAnalyzer.determineCauseChain(e);
    Exception ase = (OAuth2Exception) throwableAnalyzer.getFirstThrowableOfType(
            OAuth2Exception.class, causeChain);

    if (ase != null) {
        return handleOAuth2Exception((OAuth2Exception) ase);
    }

    ase = (AuthenticationException) throwableAnalyzer.getFirstThrowableOfType(AuthenticationException.class,
            causeChain);
    if (ase != null) {
        return handleOAuth2Exception(new UnauthorizedException(e.getMessage(), e));
    }

    ase = (AccessDeniedException) throwableAnalyzer
            .getFirstThrowableOfType(AccessDeniedException.class, causeChain);
    if (ase instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
        return handleOAuth2Exception(new ForbiddenException(ase.getMessage(), ase));
    }

    ase = (HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException) throwableAnalyzer
            .getFirstThrowableOfType(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class, causeChain);
    if (ase instanceof HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException) {
        return handleOAuth2Exception(new MethodNotAllowed(ase.getMessage(), ase));
    }

    return handleOAuth2Exception(new ServerErrorException(e.getMessage(), e));
```

it will try to get `OAuth2Exception`, `AuthenticationException`, `AccessDeniedException` in order, I think you can use this.

And you can also config the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, this filter is in the spring security chain, and it will catch and handler the exception after it, like `AuthenticationException`, `AccessDeniedException`, and it is main entry point and will be helpful for most authentication method, like `FormLogin`.

```
http
  .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(getCustomerEntryPoint());
```

If you are not use the spring oauth2, now you understand the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, so you can also implement you own `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and custom your exception response, just overrider the `commence` method, like

`BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`: it will return 'WWW-Authenticate' header
`LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`: it will redirect to target url when no authentcation