# Implement custom exception handler for error Forbidden

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create custom exception handler which returns a structured JSON response with data. I tried this:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ AccessDeniedException.class })
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> accessDeniedExceptionHandler(final AccessDeniedException ex) {
    ErrorDetail errorDetail = ErrorDetail.NOT_FOUND;

    LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
    ErrorResponse errorEntry = new ErrorResponse();
    .......

    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

Full code: [Github](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/exception/EngineExceptionHandler.java)

But I get this generic result:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-06-06T22:46:13.815+00:00",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/engine/users/request"
}
```

I want to get only this result:

```
{
  "errors": [{
    "status": 404,
    "code": "1000",
    "title": "Forbidden",
    "detail": "Forbidden",
    "extra": {
      "detail": "Forbidden"
    }
  }]
}
```

Do you know how I can send custom result and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring security - creating 403 Access denied custom response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306302/spring-security-creating-403-access-denied-custom-response)

Comment: In my case I want to use Java Class with annotation `@ExceptionHandler({ AccessDeniedException.class })` because I want to store the values into Enum. Is it possible to do this into my handler?

Comment: I highly doubt that it would be possible to do with an `@ExceptionHandler`. The reason being, the error responses are handled differently with Spring security and it would never come to the ExceptionHandler, as the response is returned elsewhere.

Comment: It might be possible to throw the exception in the custom AccessDeniedHandler implementation so that it comes to the ExceptionHandler, but that would not be a great way to handle responses.

Comment: Can you show me some example please?

Comment: **@ExceptionHandler** annotated method is only active for that particular Controller, not globally for the entire application. And let's say you have multiple controllers, So adding it to every controller makes it not well suited for a general exception handling mechanism.

Comment: Ok, Can you show me how to make custom response for Spring Security, please?

Comment: Please visit : https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring . It has a neat explanation, about different ways via which we can write custom response, along with implementation. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I think you can do custom error for access denied exception in this way

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ObjectMapper om;

    public SecurityConfiguration() {
        this.om = new ObjectMapper();
        this.om.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                om.writeValue(
                    out,
                    ErrorDto
                    .builder()
                        .code(1000)
                        .title("Forbidden")
                        .detail("Forbidden")
                        .status(404)
                    .build()
                );
                out.flush();
            }).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .formLogin().disable();
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    private static class ErrorDto{
        private int status;
        private int code;
        private String title;
        private String detail;
        // other fields
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, one additional question. I get some additional params. Do you know why and how I can remove them? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311702/remove-values-from-access-handler

Comment: check application settings for property spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion: non_null

Comment: there are several options for this setting: ALWAYS, NON_NULL, NON_ABSENT, NON_EMPTY,  NON_DEFAULT,  CUSTOM, USE_DEFAULTS, if you want separate settings for object mapper, then it's better not to inject it, but create new one and configure it for concrete case

Comment: Can you show me how to use separate settings for object mapper?

Comment: ye, sure. Check my answer. Just updated it. Look at the constructor, where I create new ObjectMapper

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a DTO class, and return as a normal response:

```
class Error {
    long status;
    long code;
    String title;
    String detail;
    Extra extra;

    // constructor for all argument...
}
```

Inside handler create an object of the above class and send the object in `ResponseEntity`:

```
Error error = new Error(args....);
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### To implement custom exception handler:

1. Specify the endpoint adress, which handles **all error types and Exceptions**, in the `web.xml`:

   ```xml
   <error-page>
       <location>/error</location>
   </error-page>
   ```
2. Add corresponding error handler method:

   ```java
   @RequestMapping(value = "/error", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public ResponseEntity<?> handleError(
           @RequestAttribute(name = "javax.servlet.error.status_code",
                   required = false) Integer errorCode,
           @RequestAttribute(name = "javax.servlet.error.exception",
                   required = false) Throwable exception) {

       if (errorCode == null) {
           errorCode = 500;
       }

       String reasonPhrase;
       if (exception != null) {
           Throwable cause = exception.getCause();
           if (cause != null) {
               reasonPhrase = cause.getMessage();
           } else {
               reasonPhrase = exception.getMessage();
           }
       } else {
           reasonPhrase = HttpStatus.valueOf(errorCode).getReasonPhrase();
       }

       HashMap<String, String> serverResponse = new HashMap<>();
       serverResponse.put("errorCode", String.valueOf(errorCode));
       serverResponse.put("reasonPhrase", reasonPhrase);

       return ResponseEntity.status(errorCode).body(serverResponse);
   }
   ```
3. Sending an `ajax` request from the frontend (I wrote it in `AngularJS`):

   ```js
   http({
       url: '/someEndpoint',
       method: "POST",
       headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
   }).then((response) => successCallback(response),
       (response) => errorCallback(response));

   let successCallback = function(response) {
       // console.log(response);
       mdToast.show({
           position: 'bottom right',
           template: scope.templates.success('Success message'),
       });
   };

   let errorCallback = function(response) {
       // console.log(response);
       mdToast.show({
           position: 'bottom right',
           template: scope.templates.error('Error message'),
       });
       if (response && response.data && response.data.reasonPhrase) {
           mdToast.show({
               position: 'bottom right',
               template: scope.templates.error(response.data.reasonPhrase),
           });
       }
   };
   ```

   First it says, that there was an error, and then says what error it was.

---

For example, if the server returns something unexpected:

```java
@GetMapping({"/", "/index.html"})
public ResponseEntity<?> getMainPage() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Something unexpected..");
}
```

The client receives this kind of `JSON` message:

```
{
    "reasonPhrase": "Something unexpected..",
    "errorCode": "500"
}
```

Or server may return something less unexpected:

```java
@GetMapping({"/", "/index.html"})
public ResponseEntity<?> getMainPage() {
    try {
        // expected actions
        // . . .
    } catch (Exception e) {
        HashMap<String, String> serverResponse = new HashMap<>();
        serverResponse.put("errorCode", "403"));
        serverResponse.put("reasonPhrase", "Forbidden");

        return ResponseEntity.status(403).body(serverResponse);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
{
    "reasonPhrase": "Forbidden",
    "errorCode": "403"
}
```

---

Also, if a client requests an unreachable resource or a page that does not exist, then he receives:

```
{
    "reasonPhrase": "Not Found",
    "errorCode": "404"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a String after using `writeValueAsString`:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(
        new ObjectMapper().writer().writeValueAsString(errorObj),
        HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
```

Comment: Can you extend a little bit the example please? Where I have to return this response?

Comment: @PeterPenzov replace last line

Comment: @PeterPenzov can you show the exception? maybe it's not `AccessDeniedException`?